# Open Select without click on child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blueprint

I'd like to know how can I open a [Select from blueprint](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/c38abd34848128d68ec65beb1cea9956904d8443/packages/select/src/components/select/select.tsx) without using the click method on the child component used to render the select.

```
<UserSelect
    items={allUsers} popoverProps={{ minimal: false }}
    noResults={<MenuItem disabled={true} text='No results.' />}
    itemRenderer={renderUser}
    itemPredicate={filterUsers}
    onItemSelect={(item,ev)=>{onItemSelectHandler(item,ev);} }>
    <p ref={usersDropdownRef} > click me test</p>
</UserSelect>
```

Instead of using **the click on the paragraph**, I'd like to set a prop in UserSelect like isOpen = {myVar}, how can I achieve a similar solution if isOpen is not available via props?

Comment: Is sharing usersDropdownRef by using a React provider or some global store or global state management library an option ? If it is the you can hide the paragraph (display: none) element while still using the ref, and from some other component you access the ref and then ```usersDropdownRef.current.click()```

Comment: I don't want to use the click event, it's causing me issues with other nested events as well, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Ok, so is there any other event you can use and trigger it programmatically ? Usually, the open/close should be determined from a state variable, so I cannot understand why props is not an option ? Maybe the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: that's correct there is a state variable in the component isOpen, I just can't access it https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/c38abd34848128d68ec65beb1cea9956904d8443/packages/select/src/components/select/select.tsx#L107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Control the underlying Popover with popoverProps={{ isOpen: true }}